# Решение задачи (praktikum)

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Решил задачу, по всем нормам, но система ругается, в чем может быть ошибка?
**Задачка:**

> Вы узнали, как сравнивать неравные объекты. С равными объектами то же самое, только оператор сравнения будет ==. Напишите код, который сравнивает половины апельсина. Программа считывает два вещественных числа — размеры половинок. Если числа равны, программа должна выводить на экран The orange is divided into two equal parts. Если первое число больше, пусть программа выводит Cut off X from the first part. Если больше второе число — пусть выводит Cut off X from the second part. Вместо X подставьте разницу в размере.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double x, z, rf;
    cin >> x >> z;
    rf = x - z;
    if (x == z) {
        cout << "The orange is divided into two equal parts" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (x > z) {
        string msg1 = "Cut off ";
        string msg2 = " from the first part";
        cout << msg1 + to_string(rf) + msg2 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (x < z) {
        string msg1 = "Cut off ";
        string msg2 = " from the second part";
        cout << msg1 + to_string(rf) + msg2 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> Задача прошла 10/31 проверок
> Возможные проблемы:

- Вы не считаете размер половинок вещественным числом
- Вы неправильно обрабатываете случай, когда первая часть больше
- Вы неправильно обрабатываете случай, когда первая часть меньше

Comment: `rf = x - z;` это наверное должно быть абсолютной величиной, иначе в одном случае из трех оно будет отрицательным.

Comment: ну и я не спец по C++, но не уверен, что числа с плавающей точкой можно так сравнивать `if (x == z)` - у вас там не требований по точности?

Comment: Во втором сравнении нужно выводить -rf

Comment: Уточните заголовок вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Вы считаете разницу в самом начале, не узнав, какое число больше - x или z. Соответственно, может получиться отрицательное число, а разница должна быть положительной. Либо используйте функцию `abs()` (оптимальный вариант), либо считайте разницу по разному для каждого случая (либо из большего вычитайте меньшее, либо выводите -rf).

Comment: Попробовал для каждого случая отдельно вычислить разницу, все равно такая же ошибка:
`int main() {
    double x, z, rf;
    cin >> x >> z;
    if (x == z) {
        cout << "The orange is divided into two equal parts" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (x > z) {
        rf = x - z;
        string msg1 = "Cut off ";
        string msg2 = " from the first part";
        cout << msg1 + to_string(rf) + msg2 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (x < z) {
        rf = z - x;
string msg1 = "Cut off ";
cout << msg1 + to_string(rf) + msg2 << endl;
return 0; `

Comment: Конкретно в этом коде в случае `if (x < z)` переменная `msg2` не определена, может в этом дело?

Comment: @yusup.abzui, количество пройденных проверок не увеличилось?

Comment: Если запускаю все нормально, только вот системе не нравится, то как я сделал:(

Comment: `main() {     double x, z, rf;     cin >> x >> z;     if (x == z) {         cout << "The orange is divided into two equal parts" << endl;         return 0;     }     if (x > z) {         rf = x - z;         string msg1 = "Cut off ";         string msg2 = " from the first part";         cout << msg1 + to_string(rf) + msg2 << endl;         return 0;     }     if (x < z) {         rf = z - x; string msg1 = "Cut off "; string msg2 = " from the second part"; cout << msg1 + to_string(rf) + msg2 << endl; return 0;` так пробовали?

Comment: @livefastdiewhenever да, не получается

Comment: А без string как-то получится сделать это задание?

Answer (score 2):

yusup.abzui!

Мне удалось решить задание, пусть и не идеально:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    // считайте два размера и определите, какой из них больше
    //Объявляем переменные
    double  a, b, x;
    string text1 = "Cut off ";
    string text2 = " from the first part";
    string text3 = " from the second part";   
    // считываем все вводимые числа
    cin >> a >> b;
    //Проверяем через условия
    if ( a == b  ) 
    {
        cout << "The orange is divided into two equal parts" << endl;
    }
     else   if ( a > b  ) 
    {
       x = a - b; // От большего вычесть меньшее
      cout << text1;  cout << x;  cout <<  text2  << endl; // Выводим результат
    }
         else   if ( b > a  ) 
    {      
      x = b - a; // От большего вычесть меньшее
      cout << text1;  cout << x;  cout <<  text3  << endl;// Выводим результат
    }
}
```